# Collating multiple Excel files into one Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I've team wise reports in .xlsx files that look like following. The files names are like team1.xlsx, team2.xlsx ... teamN.xslx

```
Date  | Report
-------------
2-Oct | Stuff 1
3-Oct | Stuff 2
```

Now I want to collate all the info into another Excel file that looks like

```
Date  | Team 1  |  Team N
--------------------------
2-Oct | Stuff 1 | Stuff N1
3-Oct | Stuff 2 | Stuff N2
```

Is this possible and if so how?

TIA

Comment: Note that if this kind of "merging" is to be run often, you would probably make a better use of a relational database (like MySQL or MS Access). That would allow you to store different data into different tables (~sheets) and make joins when reading instead of costly merges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the files team1.xlsx etc B2 to BN cells contain the data

I discovered that the data from another xlsx file maybe got as follows:

```
='C:\PathToFile\[TeamN.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2
='C:\PathToFile\[TeamN.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2
...
='C:\PathToFile\[TeamN.xlsx]Sheet1'!BN
```

Thanks all anyway!

BTW if the question/subject wasn't clear feel free to edit for others!

Answer (score 1):

See the following page on SO:

[Merge Excel Files Into One.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830841/merge-excel-files-into-one)

Answer (score 0):

Since these are text files, you could use a few Cygwin or Gnu32 command line utilities to create a single text file of the following format:

```
Team   | Date  | Report
-------------------------
Team 1 | 2-Oct | Stuff 1
Team 2 | 3-Oct | Stuff 2
...
Team N | 2-Oct | Stuff N1
Team N | 3-Oct | Stuff N2
```

Then import the new text file into Excel and then create a Pivot Table to reorganise it the way you want.

Comment: (just text) in ".xlsx files"

Comment: @Holysmoke: OK, understand you now, but don't have a solution for you.